# Vertical line in navigation menu

Tags: html, css

How can I do such a line (the white one) in a navigation menu between the li elements?

```
<ul>
<li>Info</li>
<li>Leaderboard</li>
<li>To do</li>
<li>Prizes</li>
<li>Rules</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: OK, So are your `li` elements horizontally arranged or are they vertically. Also what does that line divides?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to put a border on the left or in the middle of each LI item you can do this..

Border between each LI element..

```
    <ul>
    <li>Info</li>
    <li>Leaderboard</li>
    <li>To do</li>
    <li>Prizes</li>
    <li>Rules</li>
    </ul>

    <style>
    li {
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
    }
    </style>
```

Border on the left of each LI element

```
    <ul>
    <li>Info</li>
    <li>Leaderboard</li>
    <li>To do</li>
    <li>Prizes</li>
    <li>Rules</li>
    </ul>

    <style>
    li {
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        padding-left: 1px;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `:before` pseudo element to style the vertical divider.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0bn37mv/2/)

```
li:before{
    content: '';
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
li:first-child:before{
    content: none; /* Remove the divider from the first item */
}
```